# How to disable UICollectionViewCell's user interaction while UIImageView.image still empty

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to set `UICollectionViewCell`'s `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` while `imageView` still empty or don't let tp `performsegue` to the detail view? I'm trying to do it, but doesn't work. The example method below:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {


                cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.products.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderImage")
                cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                let p = self.products[indexPath.row] as Product

                if let img = UIImage(data: p.productImage) {
                    cell.products.image = img
                }
                else {

                    self.loadImages(p, indexPath: indexPath)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    // update some UI

                    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

                }

            }



    return cell
}
```

Comment: What does loadImages do?

Comment: it load the images from the the url in following comletionHandler block;  let taskData = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

Comment: Check my answer and see if that fits. If not we'll have to take a look at that loadImages method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making an incorrect use of `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))`. You are putting UI updates inside it (i.e. start spinner animation), and that's wrong. What I understand your code you wanted to make an asynchronous image load, and what I definitely suggest using
[SDWebImage library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to do that. It's a great library that makes a nice async image loading.

Just use it and put all that code in the main thread, so you don't need to use any dispatch_async.

Comment: first I put a placeholder image and then load product image from url. i just don't want to call storyboard segue (when clicking cell) and go to detail view before photo of product loading. because it shows empty image view if I click collectioncell before loading real image. I should disable cell's userinteractiveenable property as false or load the image on detail view's did load method if it is not load.

Comment: @MehmetTa Please, follow steps on my answer and try to do it. It should work. Seriously consider using SDWebImage and you should add code to make it enabled when the download is fnished (there is a download complete callback). That will make it work as you expect.

Comment: yes, you're right, I put UI updates inside the dispatch_sync block and it was wrong. it worked well after I put the code about preparing cell outside the block. thanks.